# weird error: Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, string, datetime, input, casting

I got this error: Input string was not in a correct format, trying to convert a value to datetime or a part of that value to int. But only with values like: "8/5/2025".

This was my first code:

```
string MyFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy";  
string MyDate = string.Empty;  
MyDate = MyObject.ValueX.ToString();  
string MyFormatedDate = Convert.toDateTime(MyDate).ToString(MyFormat);
```

I though it was the format of the datetime etc. but then I realize wasn't that because i changed my code, trying to create a DateTime object with parts like this:

```
string[] Dates= MyDate.Split('/'); 
String myYear= Dates[2].ToString().Trim(); 
String myMonth= Dates[0].ToString().Trim();
String myDay= Dates[1].ToString().Trim();   
int YearInt= Convert.ToInt32(myYear); 
int MontInt= Convert.ToInt32(myMonth); 
int DayInt= Convert.ToInt32(myDay);
DateTime newDate = new DateTime(anioInt, mesInt,diaInt);
```

I got the same error: *Input string was not in a correct format* in this line:

```
int YearInt = Convert.toInt32(myYear);
```

when myYear = "2025", if a  do this:   Convert.toInt32("2025") I don't have problems, but why I got this exception???

this is only appear when those dates.

this is MyObject use this class:

```
[DataContract]
    public class LabelField
    {
       ..
        [DataMember(Name = "ValueX")]
        public string ValueX{ get; set; }
       ..
    }
```

Comment: Use the debugger and you will find your problem a lot faster. Are you sure about the value in ValueX? And remember a string doesn't need ToString() (it is just a bit useless)

Comment: Hello Steve, thanks, but I'm using the debugger the ValueX is a string and the value is "8/5/2025",  the problem is when I try to convert using the variable does not work, but when in the debugger I try to convert using the value of the variable it works. It makes not sense.

Like this. Convert.ToInt32(myYear); and Convert.ToInt32("2025");

Comment: are you 100% sure the ValueX is the string you think it is?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my ValueX had invisible chars that I didn't see in the debugger, so I just use **Regex.Replace** and it works now.

```
String myYear= Regex.Replace(Dates[2], @"[^\x20-\x7F]", "");
String myMonth= Regex.Replace(Dates[0], @"[^\x20-\x7F]", "");
String myDay= Regex.Replace(Dates[1], @"[^\x20-\x7F]", "");
```

I didn't notice until I review the length of my variable.

I hope this solution helps some one :)

Comment: Glad to solve your problem but I think you should delete your question since it will not be helpful for future readers.